# Issue with file attachment upload and download in Azure DevOps integration with SharePoint SPFx Form Customizer

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, spfx

I'm currently working on integrating my ticketing system, which is based on SharePoint with SPFx Form Customizer, with Azure DevOps. I'm facing an issue with file attachments: when I upload files, they appear to be broken and cannot be opened in Azure DevOps.

```
type export default class AzureDevOpsService {
  constructor(organization, project, pat) {
    this.organization = organization;
    this.project = project;
    this.pat = pat;
  }
  async createTask(title, description, attachments) {
    const url = `https://dev.azure.com/${this.organization}/${this.project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=7.1-preview.3`;

    const taskData = [
        {
            op: 'add',
            path: '/fields/System.Title',
            value: title
        },
        {
            op: 'add',
            path: '/fields/System.Description',
            value: description
        }
    ];

    try {
        // Създаване на таска в Azure DevOps
        const responseTask = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`:${this.pat}`)}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(taskData)
        });

        if (!responseTask.ok) {
            const errorText = await responseTask.text();
            console.error('Error creating a task:', errorText);
            throw new Error('Error creating a task');
        }

        const resultTask = await responseTask.json();

        for (const attachment of attachments) {

            const attachmentUrl = `https://dev.azure.com/${this.organization}/${this.project}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=${encodeURIComponent(attachment.FileName)}&uploadType=simple&api-version=7.1-preview.3`;

            const responseAttachment = await fetch(attachmentUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`:${this.pat}`)}`
                },
                body: attachment.Content
            });

            if (!responseAttachment.ok) {
                const errorText = await responseAttachment.text();
                console.error('Error uploading attachment:', errorText);
                throw new Error('Error uploading attachment');
            }

            const resultAttachment = await responseAttachment.json();
            const linkUrl = `https://dev.azure.com/${this.organization}/${this.project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${resultTask.id}?api-version=7.1-preview.3`;
            const linkData = [
                {
                    op: 'add',
                    path: '/relations/-',
                    value: {
                        rel: 'AttachedFile',
                        url: resultAttachment.url,
                        attributes: {
                            comment: 'Attached File'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ];

            await fetch(linkUrl, {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`:${this.pat}`)}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(linkData)
            });
        }

        return resultTask;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
}
```

i tried converting to blob, but it didn`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that worked, thanks to Bright Ran-MSFT's help!
First I convert to Base64 string, then convert the Base64 string back into a Blob:

```
for (const attachment of attachments) {
    // Fetch the file from the URL
    const response = await fetch(attachment.Content.DecodedUrl);
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    // Convert the file content into a Base64 string
    let base64content = '';
    const len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        base64content += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    base64content = window.btoa(base64content);

    // Convert the Base64 string back into a Blob
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64content);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});

    const attachmentUrl = `https://dev.azure.com/${this.organization}/${this.project}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=${encodeURIComponent(attachment.FileName)}&uploadType=simple&api-version=7.1-preview.3`;

    const responseAttachment = await fetch(attachmentUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`:${this.pat}`)}`
        },
        body: blob
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps REST API "[**Attachments - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" seems can only support to attach text and binary modes files by default.

You might try like as below to attach the SPFx related file:

1. Try to convert the content of the SPFx related file to be Base64 string.
2. Then when calling the REST API "**Attachments - Create**", set the request body like the following.

   ```js
            const responseAttachment = await fetch(attachmentUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`:${this.pat}`)}`
                },
                body: {base64content},
                "isBase64": "Yes"
            });
   ```

---